# Fancybox overlay opens first time but not second

Tags: fancybox, overlay, opacity

I have used Fancybox plenty of times before for YouTube videos. I've never seen this problem before and can only assume it's a conflict. The Fancybox overlay opens first time but the opacity on the second attempt doesn't change from 0. When you then try again it works. It alternates. Has anyone else come across this?

Comment: show the code you are using and eventually create a jsfiddle reproducing the problem. Most likely the first time triggers a js error the prevents fancybox from working again

Comment: Thanks JFK. I'm stripping the code back to the minimum whilst replicating the problem. I'll create a jsfiddle now.